# Session state of checkbox always evaluates to true

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble getting the correct session state of a check box. If the check box is checked, it needs to be true, and if not checked, false, typical behavior. When it hits the if statement in the button click code, its evaluating to true every time. I know I'm missing something simple, but any help would be appreciated.

In Page_Load:

```
Session["FbAuth"] = false;
```

When check box is checked:

```
protected void chkFbAuth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["fbAuth"] = chkFbAuth.Checked;
    }
```

On a button click:

```
protected void btnFbAuth_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fbAuth = (bool) Session["fbAuth"];
        if (fbAuth == true)
        {
            Session["fbAuth"] = false;
            CheckAuthorization();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is a PostBack occurring when you toggle the checkbox?

Comment: No, looked to make sure AutoPostBack and CausesValidation were both false.

Comment: If there is no postback then your chkFbAuth_CheckedChanged event will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your `chkFbAuth_CheckChanged` needs to be fired to set the session variable. For this, you need a PostBack to occur. Ensure that `chkFbAuth` has `AutoPostBack="True"` and `OnCheckChanged="chkFbAuth_CheckChanged"`.